# Changing the background-color behind the text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do i change the background color inside the textarea, behind the text.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
    title      : 'Sample TextArea',
    width      : 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype     : 'textareafield',
        grow      : true,
        name      : 'message',
        fieldLabel: 'Message',
        anchor    : '100%'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
 xtype: "textarea",
 name: "editor",
 value: "",
 fieldStyle: "background: #FFFF55 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;"
}
```

Let me know this what you want